# Control the audio channel / track by using directshow?

Tags: directshow

i have write(using vb.net) a small karaoke system which can play .mpeg, .AVI, .VOB 1 format video file by using directshow. but currently i'm facing a problem which i cant control the audio channel / track in the music video. Is that any methods or ways to allow me to control the audio channel (play only backing music or vocal or both) by using directshow (in vb.net).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have the separate channels (e.g. music, vocals) recorded in separate audio streams in order to achieve this.